# Selenium code from server running on client

Tags: python, selenium, server, client

Is it possible to make some scripts using (selenium/pyautogui) written in backend to execute some actions on client? In production env?

I have a project in nodejs (backend hosted in VPS Hostinger) and nuxt (frontend hosted in Hostinger). I had a idea to do some automatizations scripts using code in python/selenium from the my project backend.

Flow: Button (client) calls a function > Frontend calls Backend > Backend executes scripts with Selenium > Selenium executes automatization actions in client.

Is that possible to do that? Or for security issues it is not possible?

I've tried to that in dev env and production env. In dev production it worked fine, i'll put the code below.

But when I try to do it on production env, I got the following error

> It has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response
> serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
> resource with CORS disabled.

I've tried to add some 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the fetch. But the same mistake shows. I do not know if I did it right.

So, I think it is not possible. Because scripts from backend running alone in the browser it seams to me dangerous.

**CODE FROM DEV ENV**

FRONTEND (NUXT)

```
async openPage({commit, state}){
    await fetch(`${state.url}/api/automatization/uploads/script-03`, {
    method: "PUT",
    })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => {
        // it prints the message from the backend
        commit('MESSAGE_RESPONSE', data)
    })
},
```

BACKEND (NODEJS)

```
router.put("/uploads/script-03", async (req, res) => {
    let options = {
        scriptPath: "scripts",
        args: JSON.stringify(req.body),
    };
  
    const goToScript = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            PythonShell.run("script-03.py", options, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {reject(err)}
                responseScript = JSON.parse(res)
                resolve(responseScript)
            })
        })
    }
    const scriptResult = await goToScript()
    console.log(scriptResult)
    res.json(scriptResult);
});
```

SCRIPT (SELENIUM)

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

client = webdriver.Chrome()

client.get("https://www.google.com/")

client.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys('cotação dolar')

client.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(10)

print(json.dumps('Código Executado!'))
```

Comment: Not a direct answer but since you're doing Google search on a string, it is probably better to just link the button to `https://www.google.com/search?q=YOUR_QUERY` (url encoded of course). If this is a test case and you're trying to do it for another site, try to find if that site has an API / you can interact with the site somehow without the use of selenium. It might be possible to have a client listen to code execution from server, but that sounds really bad security-wise.

Comment: I know what you mean! But this script with Selenium it is just a small example. There are more scripts in my code which it is not possible to take an API. I wanted to know some way to do it easily with selenium. Thanks btw